# Is moving my Windows page file to another drive good?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, pagefile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I move the page file to another physical disk location?](https://superuser.com/questions/237813/how-can-i-move-the-page-file-to-another-physical-disk-location)

I use Windows xp and also Windows 7 in my PCs. I want to know what is expected by moving page file into another drive and what benefits or bad effects it may cause. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's a separate physical drive and there's not much other contention for that drive, performance can go up.  If it's merely a separate partition on the same drive and not the partition that's most frequently accessed, performance can go down because of the time needed to move the heads back and forth between the two partitions.

Answer (score 0):

There in no risks or bad sides. For ordinary hdd its better leave it as it is. Only usage I can imagine is that you have XP/W7 installed on really slow drive and your second drive is much more faster,but having system on slowest drive doesnt make sense.