# Removing Linux from dual boot. Have Windows 7 and Kubuntu

Tags: windows-7, linux, partitioning, multi-boot, disk-management

Already gone through [windows-disk-management-not-allow-delete-volume-and-extend-volume](https://superuser.com/questions/946258/windows-disk-management-not-allow-delete-volume-and-extend-volume) but my problem is it doesn't show any menu other than **help**.

[image]

How to resolve this ?

**Edit #1:** I am using Windows 7 32 Bit.

Comment: I am tempted to flag this as unclear... what are you trying to remove, the logical drives, some other partition, or the boot menu (grub) or something else? The one you have highlighted is a Windows recovery partition and should not be removed. Removing the partitions should be easy, use any partition manager or Windows DISKPART, restoring the MBR to Windows over grub requires your Windows CD or boot media. Disk Management is not intended for managing any partitions other than Windows partitions.

Comment: @acejavelin: I want to remove the first one which is not labeled because it has Kubuntu installed on it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to fix the MBR ( Master Boot Record ). 
There are several ways to do it, i recommend you to watch this video. 
[Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TF4B1kuhqNg)

Remember you need a Windows installation, It' Easy to find. 
https://www.microsoft.com/en/software-download/windows8

Comment: Please write more information in order to explain not just a Link

Comment: That video is for Windows 8. I don't have any startup problems. It's just that I want to remove Kubuntu from dual boot.